# Validate generic input using this in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I have a html form full of inputs and I'd like to validate if it has no content using change event. I wanna do something like "when I tab this field, focus it and put a a sign if it be empty".

Comment: Can you please show what you have done so we can better assist you. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service

Comment: What Mueyiwa Moses Ikomi said, please familiarize yourself with [what topics i can ask on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Try `required` validation:

```
<input type='text' required value="some text">
```

This may be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it with required validation. But I would like to how can I do with js.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp. You need a `form` and handle `onsubmit` for this form